# Verify table with step definition also containing a table

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have this step definition:

```
    Then I verify that Ontvanger has received Type message with Onderwerp and Status
      | berichtOntvanger | berichtType | berichtOnderwerp | berichtStatus |
      | test1Rij1        | test2Rij1   | test3Rij1        | test4Rij1     |
```

Which can have one or more rows.

And now i have to verify this with a table in our application.
But i'm stuck from this point on:

```
    verifyBerichtenTableRow(table) {
        const tableContents = table.hashes();
        tableContents.forEach((element) => {
            cy.get('.berichten-centrum .p-datatable-table')
                .find('tr')
                .each(($row, $rowIndex) => {
                    if ($rowIndex >= 1) {
                        cy.wrap($row)
                            .find('td')
                            .each(($cell, $columnIndex) => {
                                cy.wrap($cell.eq($columnIndex)).should('have.text', element.DatumTijd);
                                cy.wrap($cell.eq($columnIndex)).should('have.text', element.Ontvanger);
                                cy.wrap($cell.eq($columnIndex)).should('have.text', element.Type);
                                cy.wrap($cell.eq($columnIndex)).should('have.text', element.Onderwerp);
                                cy.wrap($cell.eq($columnIndex)).should('have.text', element.stand);
                            });
                    }
                });
        });
    }
```

The test finds six 'td' in a row, which is correct but never iterates through those six. Only the first td is checked. Anyone an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be the `$cell.eq()` part. At this point you have a single cell because `.each(($cell` is taking an individual `<td>` from the collection given by `.find('td')`.

So you would only need:

```js
.find('td')
.each(($cell, $columnIndex) => {
  cy.wrap($cell).should('have.text', <element-column-here>)
})
```

But now, you need to figure out what `<element-column-here>` will be.

It looks like `element` is an object with properties corresponding to the column names,

```js
// element shape
{
  "DatumTijd": "2023-11-05",
  "Ontvanger": "John",
  "Type": "chicken",
  "Onderwerp": "How to cook"
}
```

so you should be able to use `Object.values[element][$columnIndex]`

```js
.find('td')
.each(($cell, $columnIndex) => {
  cy.wrap($cell).should('have.text', Object.values[element][$columnIndex])
})
```

---

#### Working with the cell list

Another way, change `.each($cell)` to `.then($cells)`

Now you are using the full list of cells, and can use `.eq(n)` to index individual cells.

```js
cy.wrap($row)
  .find('td')
  .then($cells => {
    cy.wrap($cells.eq(0)).should('have.text', element.DatumTijd)
    cy.wrap($cells.eq(1)).should('have.text', element.Ontvanger)
    cy.wrap($cells.eq(2)).should('have.text', element.Type)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the then() was really helpfull and now it loops through frontend table. The only thing left now is looping through the Cypress step def table, in other words when I have more than one line to check.

Comment: Hey Jasper, it should work with more than one line - the `table.hashes()` gives all the rows in the DataTable.

Comment: If the problem is coming from `cy.get(table)`, maybe add `tbody` selector as ChromeArtie suggests?